# Jquery UI Multi datepicker issue on retrieving dates

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

i am using this http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#method-addDates to enable multiple date select. everything works fine but i am wondering how to get the selected dates to PHP.

below is the html code.

```
<input type="text" name="outgoing_call_dates" value="" id="outgoing_call_dates_id" class="hasDatepicker">
```

as you can see value tag is empty always when i add, its normally appending to the end but not value tag is doing the same. please check this image.

Original source : http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#method-addDates (example : From input)

Please help me find a way[image]

Comment: can you provide any fiddle ??

Comment: here is it http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<input id="datePick" type="text"/>

<input id="get" type="button" value="Get" />
```

JS

```
$('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();

$('#get').on("click",function(){
    var dates = $('#datePick').val();
        if(dates !=''){
        dataString = 'dates='+dates;
        $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url : "URL_TO_PHP_FILE",
                 data : dataString,
                 dataType : 'json',
                 success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
               }
        )};
      }
});
```

PHP

```
$dates = ($_POST['dates']);
 echo json_encode($dates);
```

Comment: not it doesnt work that way. thats why i was confused. alert() prints undefined. this is how i do it. var date = ("#outgoing_call_dates_id").val();
 alert(date);

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3t4j9/4/ (not fully completed)

Comment: after doing the way u suggested. i kpet getting the output as Object object. then i tried doing the alert this way.. alert(JSON.stringify(dates)); but still the output is as following... :( {"context":{"jQuery17109960364635720899":1,"location":{}},"selector":"#outgoing_call_dates_id"}

Answer (score 1):

`value` attribute defines default value. If you change the value of input element, it won't be inside source with `value="YOUR_ENTERED_VALUE"` .

To access value in client side, you can use JS or jQuery.

For example using jQuery:

```
var dates = $('#outgoing_call_dates_id').val();
```

In pure JS:

```
var dates = document.getElementById('outgoing_call_dates_id').value;
```

For PHP,
when you'll receive it on your action page. 
On that page,

use this:

```
$dates = $_POST['outgoing_call_dates'];
```

or

```
$dates = $_GET['outgoing_call_dates'];
```

depending on the method you use.

Comment: actually i know this thing. the issue is i am getting this variable as undefined.  i mean if alert or console.log its outputting as undefined.

Comment: A fiddle will help to identify the issue.

Comment: tnx but i think this normally works and the issue i am having is something else. i am doing it in a seperate window (iframe) and after i submit it gets hidden then after that when i try to access an hidden element that undefiend erro comes. i need to resolve it; tnx for everyones support

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look @ this....!
Hope this will fix your issue :)

```
<no codes :|>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/23/